# How to connect mongodb with meteor

Tags: meteor

I try to connect the mongodb with meteor app..But its not connecting. I place this code in settings.Json to connect with db

"env":{
    "MONGO_URL":"mongodb://localhost:27017/wesendit"
  },

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following MONGO_URL syntax to connect the database

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/database
```

To connect with authentication

```
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://username:password@domain.com:database/'
```

Comment: Im not familiar with meteor so i didnt know where to place these

Comment: You can run meteor app like this  this:  export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/database&& meteor